# return max value between 2 range of field in mysqli/php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that is ordered by `id` starting from 1.

I also have a timestamp order for each record as `'stamptime'`

I try to return max `'stamptime'` between `id=10` and `id=15`.  I tried this code but without success...

```
 $sql = "SELECT MAX(stamptime) as max, id FROM Articls ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10, 15";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $this->disconnectDB($conn);
        return $row['0'];
```

what's the correct way to do this?

Comment: `LIMIT 10,15 ` seems wrong - especially when ordering in DESCending order. How about `WHERE id >=10 AND ID <= 15`? Might try ASC as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `limit`, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html, is for how many rows to return. You want to use `between`, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between.

```
SELECT MAX(stamptime) as max, id FROM Articls where id between 10 and 15
```

Your current code said select the max timestamp which would be returned as row 1. The order though said to start returning at row 11 and return 15 rows, which all would be empty. From the limit doc, `the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(STAMPTIME) AS MAX FROM ARTICLS WHERE ID>9 AND ID<16 ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that you shouldn't need "Order by" if I have your structure pictured correctly, because you should only get one row returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only `order by` clause with `desc` and then `limit 1`

```
select
stamptime,
id 
from Articls
where id between 10 and 15
order by stamptime desc limit 1
```